# the output of the array in turn in panel to labels C#

Tags: c#, arrays, label, panel

I faced with the problem. I have a panel with 20 labels. The function generator() assign each label the number of the array. Each number scrolls from 1 to needed number. But the problem is that the number is assigned out of order. For example first number assign to 1 label and the next number to 10 label, the next to 2 and the next to 11 etc.

But I need to output the numbers in rtl or ltr order.

I dont know how to fix it. Help, please.

[image: how the problem looks like]

```
public void generator() // присваивание текстбоксам значений 
    {
        generatedArray = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();

       for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < generatedArray[i] + 1; j++)
            {
                panel1.Controls[i].Text = j.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                panel1.Controls[i].Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

I would be grateful for help :)

Comment: Use `Thead.Sleep` is not an appropriate way to animate your UI.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i know it, but it not my current problem :)

Comment: `panel1.Controls` is not a nicely ordered collection (well, it may be, but I doubt we know the internal order of things). I suggest you intelligently name your label controls in a manner that allows you to address them using `panel1.FindControl(lblName)` constructing lblName based on your `getUniqueRandomArray` index.

Comment: Without know more of what you want to do it's hard to say, but a couple of things stand out.  You update the same `panel1.Controls[i]` each time through the j loop and a 50msec sleep isn't going to be visible.  The result will be as if you replaced the inner loop with `panel1.Controls[i].Text = generatedArray[i].ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, you could use some controls of your own, so that you can better define their behaviour (and do it in batch).

A custom class which derives from Label:

```
List<MyLabel> MyLabels = new List<MyLabel>();

public class MyLabel : Label
{
   public MyLabel()
   {
      //Define some default properties
      this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
      this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
      this.Font = new Font("Calibri", 9f, FontStyle.Regular);
      this.BackColor = Color.White;
      this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      this.Size = new Size(50, 20);
   }
}
```

Insert an array of custom labels inside a panel (this could be a custom control too).

```
 int LeftMargin = 20;
 int TopMargin = 20;
 int NumberOfLabels = 20;
 int LabelsPerRow = 5;
 int LabelsDistance = 10;
 int _idx = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < (NumberOfLabels / LabelsPerRow); y++)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < LabelsPerRow; x++)
   {
      MyLabels.Add(new MyLabel() { Parent = this.panel1 });
      MyLabels[_idx].Location = new Point((LeftMargin + ((MyLabels[_idx].Width + LabelsDistance) * x)),
                                          (TopMargin + ((MyLabels[_idx].Height + LabelsDistance) * y)));
      _idx++;
   }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

if you simply change these fields:

```
 int LeftMargin = 1;
 int TopMargin = 1;
 int NumberOfLabels = 20;
 int LabelsPerRow = 20;
 int LabelsDistance = 1;
```

you get this:

[image]

Then, call your `generator()` method to fill the UI:

```
generator();

public async void generator()
{
   generatedArray = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < MyLabels.Count; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 1; j < generatedArray[i] + 1; j++)
      {
         await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(500));

         //Set the text property of the custom labels. The order will be respected
         MyLabels[i].Text = j.ToString();
      }
}
```

You could also set the labels text property through the Panel.Controls[] array.

```
this.panel1.Controls[i].Text = j.ToString();
```

The order would be respected as well, but if the parent form closes, it causes an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception.

Comment: i added a picture on first post to uderstand the problem. your method i cant to try because it little different from my work. can u help by fixing your code?

Comment: @Syncmaxim  What do you mean with "fix it"? That you need your labels in a single line?

Comment: i mean to do it simly, without classes and initialization each label. your method works, it is good, but is big. I solved this problem simply:
i've remove all labels from this panel and added them again one by one. Now it works good. :) Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Syncmaxim  Well, good for you, but I suggest to reconsider. You should have direct control on the disposition of your objects. There's no guarantee that your container will respect that order in the future. See also the edit.